# Is it possible to separate a subject from context?

Tags: user-centered-design

This is a bit of a theoretical but I wonder if its meaningfully possible to separate the context from the subject when studying the context of a particular subject.

For example, would there be a meaningful difference if I worked with UX and studied the context of a water-purification plant worker without knowing anything about chemistry or the concepts of water purification beyond basics? My position is that these "details" and the subject (chemistry) are needed and are part of that context that is used to inform the user experience and creating appropriate interactions and/or interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible.**

I've worked in health and finance settings and I did not have to read about physiology or get a finance certification. In most organizations, there are usually people or teams that are required to have huge domain expertise in the business area, UX designers are not top of that list.

While it remains helpful to someone working in cryptocurrency to have a mid-level understanding of how cryptocurrency works, your knowledge of blockchain does not necessarily make you a better UX Designer.

**See it from this perspective: Most of your users are not domain experts in these fields. Even expert users are not necessarily theoretical domain geniuses.** An expert Photoshop user does not necessarily need to know the ancient history of graphic design.

A designer without development experience may struggle to work for a company like GitHub but you will do just fine if all you know are Git basics, Terminal familiarity. You do not have to understand abstraction or algorithms.